# Maximum number of tags allowed in OpenTsdb

Tags: tags, opentsdb

What is the maximum number of tags allowed in openTsdb? I read some of the documents and it seems that the default value is 8. But I am confused that whether the maximum number is 8 or is it configurable to a higher value.
I know lesser number of tags should be kept, but its the requirement.
So can I have more number of tags than 8?

Comment: OpenTSDB supports max 8 tags out of the box. If you need support for more tags, you'll need to fork OpenTSDB and update MAX_NUM_TAGS in core/Const.java to suit your requirement. But be advised that having a lot of tags will affect the performance and storage.

Comment: BTW, tag width will be configurable starting 2.2 - http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/new.html

Comment: Right I also got the link for setting the tags number in core/const.java but I am unable to find the file, I tried to set the value in conf file but it didn't pick up. Sorry the question is naive but can you please direct me the location of const.java

Comment: Here is the link to the file. https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/blob/v2.1.3/src/core/Const.java. Configuring tag width is different. It's about whether to use 3 byte ids (default) or something else.

Answer (score 3):

It is now configurable, at least it is in version 2.3.1.

A snippet from Const.java:

```
static void setMaxNumTags(final short tags) {
  if (tags < 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("tsd.storage.max_tags must be greater than 0");
  }
  MAX_NUM_TAGS = tags;
}
```

And then a snippet from TSDB.java:

```
public TSDB(final HBaseClient client, final Config config) {
  ...
  if (config.hasProperty("tsd.storage.max_tags")) {
    Const.setMaxNumTags(config.getShort("tsd.storage.max_tags"));
  }
  ...
}
```

Just setting the `"tsd.storage.max_tags"` value in opentsdb.conf and a restart is enough.
The file can be found at `/usr/share/opentsdb/etc/opentsdb/` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use too many tags, keep it to a fairly small number, usually up to 4 or 5 tags (By default, OpenTSDB supports a maximum of 8 tags).

```
OpenTSDB does not support more than 8 tags. and it is not configurable.
```

Comment: what if I upgrade to version 2.2??

Answer (score 1):

Not configurable but still easy to reach. You can change the source code src/core/Const.java change MAX_NUM_TAGS  to some number you want.

https://github.com/StumbleUponArchive/opentsdb/blob/e68948bc/src/core/Const.java#L22

But if you really need a lot of tags you should try some other products like elasticsearch.